# Use File Content to Determine MIME Type with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, mime-types

It seems all of the popular MIME type libraries for node.js just use the file name extension rather than peeking into the file to determine the MIME type.

Is there a good way to use Node to jump into the file and intelligently determine the file's MIME type in case an extension is not present?

Answer (score 10):

That indeed feels like a pity, that most popular *MIME* modules are just mapping extension to the type.

After searching deeper, I found the module called [*mmmagic*](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic), it seems to be doing exactly what you want.

Be aware, that from working with *MIME* I was left with a taste, that *MIME* detection is in principle not completely reliable, and there is a rare chance of false detections.

Example of usage (taken from [their](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic) site):

```
  var mmm = require('mmmagic'),
      Magic = mmm.Magic;

  var magic = new Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
  magic.detectFile('node_modules/mmmagic/build/Release/magic.node', function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      // output on Windows with 32-bit node:
      //    application/x-dosexec
  });
```

Comment: Multer, Formidable, mime-types, file-type return file type depends on the extension. With the same file, when I change the extension, I will get another mime type. Only mmmagic really works!

Answer (score 3):

Since MIME does not at all dictate anything about the file contents format, you can only employ heuristics to guess what is going on in a file:

1. Some binary formats have something called a magic number, but those can be wrong or ambiguous. [See this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) for more info.
2. Many text file formats contain grammar constructs that you can use for a simple pattern matching test. E.g. `xml`, `csv` or `json`. However some formats (e.g. `HTML`), have a rather "evolved" syntax definition making it ambiguous and thus hard to pattern match.

To better illustrate the issue of ambiguity, here is an example: Browsers have developed a very very high tolerance, and accept anything that remotely resembles `HTML` thus a `HTML` (or even `XHTML`) file format is hard to identify. Not to mention the fact that `HTML` files could actually be non-`HTML` template languages (such as `jade`, `handlebars`, `angular` templates etc...). This is just one of many examples where things get very ambiguous.